# Alternative of cvGetWindowHandle() in opencv4+

Tags: c++, opencv, mfc

I am using Opencv3.4.8 in my MFC application. I am using cvGetWindowHandle() to get the handle of the window as follows;

```
namedWindow(windowname, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
HWND hWnd = (HWND) cvGetWindowHandle(windowname.c_str());
HWND hParent = ::GetParent(hWnd);
::SetParent(hWnd, GetDlgItem(IDC_PICTURE)->m_hWnd);
::ShowWindow(hParent, SW_HIDE);
CWnd* pWnd = new CWnd();
pWnd->CWnd::Attach(hParent);
```

Now I want to upgrade to Opencv4+ and there is no cvGetWindowHandle() in Opencv4+. I want to know if there is an alternative function in Opencv4+ and if not how can I do the same task in opencv4+.

Comment: It looks like you didn't include the right header file for `cvGetWindowHandle`, it's unlikely that they removed it.

Comment: I checked the documentation as it says it has been removed.

Comment: Use Windows API `::FindWindow(NULL, windowname.c_str());` or `::FindWindowEx`

Comment: I does work but the opencv window is not docked in the main window. I guess I can make it work. Will show my code when i get the desired result. thanks.

Comment: `SetParent` is a problem here because OpenCV has its own message loop that's separet from MFC. Explain the whole application and what it is trying to do. For example, is it reading video input? You can create MFC window and redirect OpenCV to that window.

Comment: I am reading a video input and showing it through MFC picture control. The code is self explanatory. It works fine now for both OpenCv3 and OpenCV4. I am not sure if i can just redirect OpenCv video input to an MFC window.

Answer (score 2):

[#3091](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/pull/3091). getWindowProperty(window_name, WND_PROP_AUTOSIZE) >= 0 should be replacement of cvGetWindowHandle()

Comment: the return type of getWindowProperty(window_name, WND_PROP_AUTOSIZE)  is double. Its not possible to cast a double to HWND.

Answer (score 1):

just include

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
```

and than u can use cvGetWindowHandle() furthermore.

Greets DiebBlue

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who are still using Opencv in MFC DialogBox, there is a different solution

FindWindows returns the Parent Window handle, and MFC works with the child window, so you'll need FindWindow and FindWindowEx.

New source code for MFC and Opencv4+

```
namedWindow(windowname, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

////// This will work on opencv 4.X //////

HWND hParent = (HWND)FindWindow(NULL, windowname.c_str());
HWND hWnd = (HWND)FindWindowEx(hParent, NULL, L"HighGUI class", NULL);

::SetParent(hWnd, GetDlgItem(IDC_PICTURE)->m_hWnd);
::ShowWindow(hParent, SW_HIDE);

CWnd* pWnd = new CWnd();
pWnd->CWnd::Attach(hParent);
```

Maybe you're still in troubles because string to LPCWSTR conversion fails, and hParent returns NULL. There is many ways to convert string to LPCWSTR, but because you are using MFC, try

```
namedWindow(windowname, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

////// This will work on opencv 4.X //////

CString CstrWindowname = windowname.data();
    
HWND hParent = (HWND)FindWindow(NULL, CstrWindowname);
HWND hWnd = (HWND)FindWindowEx(hParent, NULL, L"HighGUI class", NULL);

::SetParent(hWnd, GetDlgItem(IDC_PICTURE)->m_hWnd);
::ShowWindow(hParent, SW_HIDE);

CWnd* pWnd = new CWnd();
pWnd->CWnd::Attach(hParent);
```

The new code should replace this old code

```
namedWindow(windowname, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

///// OLD version. Used on opencv 3.X on MFC Dialog Box /////

HWND hWnd = (HWND) cvGetWindowHandle(windowname.c_str());    
HWND hParent = ::GetParent(hWnd);

::SetParent(hWnd, GetDlgItem(IDC_PICTURE)->m_hWnd);
::ShowWindow(hParent, SW_HIDE);

CWnd* pWnd = new CWnd();
pWnd->CWnd::Attach(hParent);
```

Try,

Answer (score 0):

I am using **OpenCV4.5.0 with QT** in my application. The version of QtSdk is Qt5.14.2.
**The window of 'imshow' is embedded in a QWidget in my application.**

```
 #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>

...

/**
* @brief MainWindow::EmbedCvWindow
* @param pWnd : a handle of parent window
* @param strWndName: name of opencv`s window 
* @param w: widget`s width
* @param h: widget`s height
*/
void MainWindow::EmbedCvWindow( HWND pWnd, QString strWndName, int w, int h )
{
    // create a window named 'strWndName'. OpenCVSdk is compiled with Qt,So the parameter is set to 'CV_GUI_NORMAL', it has no status bar and  no tool bar
    cvNamedWindow(strWndName.toStdString().c_str(), CV_GUI_NORMAL);// flag is only for Qt

    //The cvWindow of opencv with qt is a subclass of QWidget,so it can`t get right result by nomal method.     
    //HWND hWnd =  (HWND)cvGetWindowHandle(strWndName.toStdString().c_str());
    
    //first way: get the handle of independent window 'imshow' 
    //HWND hWnd =  (HWND)(((QWidget*)cvGetWindowHandle(strWndName.toStdString().c_str()))->winId());
    
    //second way:get the handle of independent window 'imshow' by winAPI 'FindWindow'
    HWND hWnd =::FindWindow(NULL,strWndName.toStdWString().c_str()); 

    // get the handle of parent window 'imshow'
    HWND hParent = ::GetParent((HWND)hWnd);
    
    // The client area of 'imshow' is embedded in a QWidget in my application.
    ::SetParent(hWnd, pWnd);

    // hide status bar and tool bar,
    ::SetWindowLong(hWnd,GWL_STYLE,WS_CLIPCHILDREN|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS|WS_CHILDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE);
    ::SetWindowLong(hWnd,GWL_EXSTYLE,WS_EX_LEFT|WS_EX_RTLREADING/*|WS_EX_TOPMOST*/);

    //hide the old parent window of 'imshow'
    ::ShowWindow(hParent, SW_HIDE);

    //resize width and height of client area 
    cvResizeWindow(strWndName.toStdString().c_str(), w,h);
    
    //set postion of client area. (very importent)
    cvMoveWindow(strWndName.toStdString().c_str(),0,0); 
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer? Some descriptive comments would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: After changing the parent window, the position of the current child window cannot be determined, so it is likely to appear in an invisible area. You need to set the position of the child window.   cvMoveWindow(strWndName.toStdString().c_str(),0,0)

Answer (score 0):

```
namedWindow ("SrcView", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
HWND hWnd = (HWND)cvGetWindowHandle ("SrcView");
HWND hParent = (HWND)FindWindow (NULL, L"SrcView");
HWND hOrgParent = ::SetParent (hWnd, GetDlgItem (IDC_STATIC_SRC_VIEW)->m_hWnd);
::ShowWindow (hOrgParent, SW_HIDE); // This row is important, if you comment this row, an extra window will be showed)
```

This works for my MFC application no matter it is using OpenCV 3.1 or OpenCV 4.5